# In an Ionic React application, how can i change the value for 'canDismiss' when using the 'useIonModal' hook?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have tried everything i can think of at this point in attempting to achieve a simple modal that requires that the user click a button (confirm or cancel) before the modal can dismiss.

In an Ionic React functional component, i have tried to instantiate a modal for this purpose using the `useIonModal` hook with the `canDismiss` property initially set to `false` with the intent to change `canDismiss` after the user clicks one of the buttons inside the modal. I have tried changing `canDismiss` via both local state using the `useState` hook as well as with global state via a `react-redux` store among other ways noted below. Nothing i have tried manages to change the value of `canDismiss` for the modal.

The code inside my functional component:

```
// I initially set canDismiss to false here
const [canDismiss, setCanDismiss] = useState(false);

const [presentDialog, dismissDialog] = useIonModal(Dialog, {
    // When user clicks a button in the modal, the modalComplete method is called passing its payload to this parent
    modalComplete: (payload) => {modalCompleteHandler(payload)}
});

// this is the method which is executed via the modal which attempts to set canDismiss to true
const modalCompleteHandler = useCallback((payload) => {
  setCanDismiss(() => { return true });
  // do stuff with the payload
}, []);

// i attempt to watch for the change in a useEffect hook and when attempting to dismiss the dialog after the change canDismiss === true, the dialog does NOT dismiss
useEffect(() => {
 if(canDismiss) {
   dismissDialog();
 }
}, [canDismiss, dismissDialog]);

// this is the method that displays the modal with canDismiss set to false via useState hook noted above
const showDialogHandler = useCallback(()=> {
  presentDialog({
   canDismiss: canDismiss,
  });
}, [canDismiss, presentDialog]);
```

I have tried to change the value for `canDismiss` with and without a `useEffect` hook as outlined above by also attempting to dismiss the modal immediately after setting `canDismiss` to `true` instead. This also did not work:

```
setCanDismiss(() => { return true });
dismissDialog();
```

I have tried using state inside a `react-redux` store globally for changing the value of `canDismiss`. This also did not work:

```
..
presentDialog({
  canDismiss: uiState.modal.canDismiss,
});
...
dispatch(actionsUI.setCanDismiss({canDismiss: true}));
```

I have tried setting the value for `canDismiss` to `true` in the  `react-redux` store from the parent component as well as *inside* the modal component `Dialog` prior to calling its `modalComplete` method with `payload`. Neither worked.

I have tried storing the value for `canDismiss` using a simple object with `useMemo` in the parent component. This also does not work:

```
const canDismissState = useMemo(() => { return {value: false} },[]);
...
canDismissState.value = true;
dismissDialog();
```

And lastly, i have tried using a `ref` which also does not work:

```
const canDismissRef = useRef({value: false});
...
canDismissRef.current.value = true;
dismissDialog();
```

Absolutely nothing seems to change the value for `canDismiss` after the modal is presented using the `useIonModal` hook. Why?

I do **NOT** want to stuff a modal in my JSX with the necessary attributes as a solution.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the value of `canDismiss` to a function that returns a promise which resolves to `true` or `false` is the solution i was looking for.

As an example, here is one possible implementation which uses another ionic hook to achieve the goal:

```
const [present] = useIonActionSheet();
...
function canDismissFunc() {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      present({
        header: 'Are you sure?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            role: 'confirm',
          },
          {
            text: 'No',
            role: 'cancel',
          },
        ],
        onWillDismiss: (ev) => {
          if (ev.detail.role === 'confirm') {
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        },
      });
    });
}
...
// and when presenting the modal
presentDialog({
  canDismiss: canDismissFunc,
});
```